# Issue with regular links and use of pushstate and popstate

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

This is how my flow works. User clicks on a link - "<kbd>find</kbd>", and is shown a page using ajax. I add to history using `pushState`. Then, the user clicks next to see results of page 2(using ajax), and I add again to push state. So, this works fine, when the user goes back. But, my issue is that say user is on page 2 of results, and clicks a regular link(i e no ajax call). He is taken to a new page, but when he clicks back, he is not taken to results page 2 but to the initial search page.

Is this normal behavior? Or can something be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your search/result page is not properly updating its state when loaded. When you go back from "regular page", the "ajax page" is reloaded and thus loses its state. You must manually restore the state (e.g. read the url and doing the corresponding ajax).

Comment: what happens is that the address bar shows /result/?index=20 and immediately changes to /result/?index=0 !! ( I am displaying 20 results per page)

Comment: What happens when you go to /result/?index=20 by entering the address instead of using the back button?

Comment: same result!! goes to /result/?index=0

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing the code, but could it be that your code is doing pushState with index=0?